# Too frequent disk checks on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: fsck

I want to report a problem or any improper programming .

Some time ago to install Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit on my computer.

I realized that when the operating system always checking the message I get the filesystem .

Or rather the Linux fsck

But I realized that this is being done very often

Someone knows why this originates ?.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is.. Please explain in more detail?

Comment: Greeting:

You better explain the issue , always on time to start the operating system Ubuntu displays an image such as this :  http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-u3uZiqpdrOY/UYFpnh2jrEI/AAAAAAAAGeQ/FHAM2BI3-_4/s1600/ubuntu-bootsplash-pantalla-de-arranque.png

Ubuntu logo below the disk check message appears, but the disk check is done very often

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a boot option. If you would like to turn it off, follow these steps:

Open `/etc/fstab` with your desired text editor. I will use gedit, but you can use any text editor.

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

You will see all of your drives, and allocations. You will see a line that looks like this:

`UUID=(Your harddrive's UUID)     /        ext4       defaults    0      (1 or 2)`

This is a boot option and location assigner. In the line, there should be either a 1 or a 2 for the second number. Replace it with a zero, now save and reboot. Done!